# Network/DNS SELinux issues on RHEL

Tags: rhel, networkmanager

```
[root@notebook log]# grep -i network yum.log
Nov 18 14:59:58 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-libnm-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 14:59:59 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-glib-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:04 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:11 Updated: NetworkManager-libreswan-1.2.4-1.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:12 Updated: NetworkManager-libreswan-gnome-1.2.4-1.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:18 Updated: network-manager-applet-1.4.0-2.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:18 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-wwan-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:18 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-tui-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:18 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-team-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Nov 18 15:00:18 Updated: 1:NetworkManager-wifi-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
[root@notebook log]#
```

After a RHEL7 networkmanager update, many people are affected.

After the networkmanager update, they cannot connect to any network, VPN, etc.

Q: what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**temporary SOLUTION:**

the config of selinux should look like this to get it work:

```
[root@notebook ~]# egrep -vi '^#|^$' /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=permissive
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
[root@notebook ~]#
```

reboot needed!

don't forget to set selinux back to enforced when networkmanager is fixed...

UPDATE: fixed selinux packages came out, it works now, ENFORCE the selinux back!

```
[root@notebook log]# cat yum.log 

Nov 22 07:51:26 Updated: libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:26 Updated: libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:26 Updated: libsemanage-2.5-4.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:26 Updated: libsemanage-python-2.5-4.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:27 Updated: libselinux-python-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:27 Updated: libselinux-utils-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:27 Updated: policycoreutils-2.5-8.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:27 Updated: selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch
Nov 22 07:51:27 Updated: setools-libs-3.3.8-1.1.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:28 Updated: libsepol-devel-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:28 Updated: checkpolicy-2.5-4.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:28 Installed: libsepol-2.5-6.el7.i686
Nov 22 07:51:28 Updated: policycoreutils-python-2.5-8.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:29 Updated: libselinux-devel-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
Nov 22 07:51:45 Updated: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch
Nov 22 07:51:45 Updated: libselinux-2.5-6.el7.i686
[root@notebook log]#
```

Comment: SELinux mode can be set without reboot with `setenforce`. (Note that this effectively disables all SELinux checks.)

Comment: I agree precisely is setenforce 0 to disable and 1 to reenable

Comment: The question doesn't detail the precise problem. Disabling SELinux entirely seems a very bad solution.